# CakePHP custom paginator

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I made a paginator but the problem is that it shows page number on bottom when there is only one page. So I tried to add if~else but I can't get it to work. "Error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded "

**before**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++): ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $x; ?>"<?php if($page === $x) { echo ' class="selected" '; } ?>><?php echo $x ?></a>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

**after**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
       if($pages > 1){
           for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++): 
              if($x = 1)
              { 
              ?>
               <a href="?page=<?php echo $x; ?>"<?php if($page === $x) { echo ' class="selected" '; } ?>><?php echo $x ?></a>
              <?php
              } else {
                echo '';
              }
           endfor;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$pages` is the total count of pages you have, you need to wrap your custom pagination in an `if` statement to check you have more than 1 page before displaying your pagination.

```
<?php if ($pages > 1): ?>
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++): ?>
            <a href="?page=<?php echo $x; ?>"<?php if($page === $x) { echo ' class="selected" '; } ?>><?php echo $x ?></a>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Your code is breaking because you are doing the `if` statement inside your `for` loop and setting the value of `$x` to `1` every time (you're using `=` instead of `==`). This will get you stuck in an infinite loop.

If you're using CakePHP is there a reason why you are not using it's inbuilt [Pagination](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html)? The [`PaginatorHelper`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper) should provide you all the methods you need to display pagination if you are.